# What is best way to have several child processes in C

Tags: c, multithreading, multiprocessing

Working on a project that request to download about 300 pics from different locations by using `wget` every 20 minutes.
I wrote a C program that reads the database for all the Ids and locations into an array.
For each entry in the array, I call the external `wget` command to download it.
It works but is slow because it is doing one by one.

My thinking is to use either Multi-process, multi-thread or openMP to create several children.
Any suggestion for how to do this is appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

**Multiple Processes**

An error in one process cannot crash another process.  This is particularly useful when you will host third-party code (e.g. plugins), and this is the approach that (among others) Google Chrome takes.  The disadvantage is that *N* processes use more system resources than *N* threads.

**Multiple Threads**

Uses fewer system resources than an equivalent number of processes.  Thread programming is more error prone for many developers, and an error in one thread can affect other threads.

**Best Option**

For what you are doing, you are unlikely to see a significant difference in resource utilization.  Use whichever model you can write fast in high quality.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would go for multi process. The wget's do not need to share any memory or communicate (other than an exit status which is only needed by the root) so a thread will not provide any additional benefit (in my opinion). As well as this creating them as processed allows the OS scheduler to best decide when to run each process.

Comment: wget is a child process anyhow.  It really boils down to whether the controlling process that launches the wget calls should be multi-threaded.